# How does Python global variables resolution between packages work?

Tags: python, inheritance, global-variables

How does Python resolve global variables in calls between packages, especially in cases there are global variables with the same name present?

For example. Let there ba a package `P1` containing `BaseClass`. Let there be two packages `P2` and `P3`, containing classes `Derived1` and `Derived2` that inherit `BaseClass` correspondingly. Also, let `P2` and `P3` both contain variable named `gvar` (for example, defined in their **init**.py files).

Both of derived classes in their constructors have a call to `baseClass` constructor through `super`.

If in `BaseClass` constructor there is a reference to `gvar`, what would happen? Is there a way to ensure that during instantiation of `Derived1` `gvar` from `P2` would be used?

Why am i bothering with global variables: in my real life case there are tens of classes in `P1` and `P2`, and i would like to avoid changing them all (to add package-specific `gvar` to their definitions, or adding another common ancestor with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globals are *per module*. Globals in `P1`, `P2` and `P3` are all independent.

Python functions also store a pointer to the globals mapping of their module, so even when imported, globals are still looked up in the module they were defined in.

For your example ,that means that a global referenced from `P2.Derived1.__init__` is looked up in `P2`, and a global referenced from `P3.Derived2.__init__` is looked up in `P3`. Both packages would need to *import* `P1.BaseClass`, and any globals `P1.BaseClass.__init__` might look up are sourced from `P1`.

Comment: Well, i presumed that it was possible that the global context of calling function is passed down to its callees, and so `P1.BaseClass.__init__` would have access to globals available for the `P2.Derived1.__init__` that called it.

Comment: @Srv19: nope, that's not how Python works. That would be incredibly impractical, because that would require you to import all globals any code you wanted to use needed. For example, the `argparse` module imports `os`, `re`, `sys`, `textwrap` and `copy`. If globals needed to be taken from the caller namespace, you'd have to import those modules too just to be able to run `argparse` in your code.

Comment: i do not understand. Why is there a need to import anything else? I mean, global variables should be accessible (or not, depending on execution context) by name without importing them - it is dynamic language after all, not C where evarything should be known at compile time

Comment: @Srv19: What I meant is that you have to pick one model over another. Either you have dynamic scoping (and the names are looked up in the caller namespace), or you have static scoping (what Python uses, and the module in which a function is defined determines where globals are found). Your presumption was that Python would use dynamic scoping, and if that was the case, then you'd have to use additional imports. I was illustrating how impractical that'd be.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up for me

Answer (score 0):

"Global" variables are only global to the module (i.e., the file) in which they are defined.  If you have a function (including a method) in a given file, and that function refers to a global variable `gvar`, it will always refer to a global variable `gvar` within that module, not in any other module.

You can, however, modify or create global variables from outside the module.  For instance, if you do `import blah` and then `blah.gvar = 2`, you have effectively created a global variable `gvar` inside `blah` (or changed its value, if it already existed), and code inside `blah` that refers to `gvar` will use the value you have set.